# Erro ao receber conteúdo do Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho um cadastro de cliente e preciso em certo momento alterar o cadastro do mesmo, mas para fazer a alteração tenho que tratar de um campo Picker, só que dá erro quando tento trazer o conteúdo que está gravado nele para logo depois, se necessário, alterar.

O erro:

"Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Código do Picker (com outros campos para exemplificar melhor):

```
pckUF.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(clienteAlterar.UF);
entryIBGE.Text      = clienteAlterar.COD_IBGE;
entryTel1.Text      = clienteAlterar.FONE1;
```

Observação: Se retiro o Picker do meu código (nessa parte de Alteração) todos os campos recebem normalmente seu conteúdo, ficam prontos para serem alterados.

Comment: `clienteAlterar.UF` é uma string com conteúdo numérico válido? É isso que a validação está reclamando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava buscando um modo de alterar na internet e consegui. Na realidade eu estou conhecendo as ferramentas e entendi que eu estava precisando do SelectedItem (pegar o conteúdo) e não do SelectedIndex (não índice), com isso tirei o Convert e foi:

```
pckUF.SelectedItem  = clienteAlterar.UF;
```

Mas agradeço pelo retorno @Diego.